# Firebase Dynamic Link Not Redirecting To Instant App

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, android-instant-apps

I'm using Firebase **Dynamic Links** with the android **instant app** and but instead of **redirecting to the instant app** it is **opening** the URL in the **browser**.

I tried adding the "**afl**" param but it is also not working.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hello i am facing same issue in ios